# Why is the value not assigned to the variable in case of an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

```
(function() {
    var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log(a, b);



(function() {
    var x = y = 3;
    console.log(x, y);    
})();
```

These are very simple program. But I'm confused why `a` is undefined while `b` has value 3 in the output of the first example  program while both `x` and `y` are having the value 3 in the second example program?

Comment: because you set var  a in the function scope in the first IIFE. = b => b is globally assigned without var. Sorry, no time for the backgrounds, so just a comment ;)

Comment: Even a comment is fine @Dominik. Thanks for taking time in posting a comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically `var a = b = 3;` is equivalent to `var a = (b = 3);` and you may know in JavaScript the variable can be defined without `var` keyword and when you declare a variable without `var` keyword then the variable would be in the global scope so outside IIFE you log b and results to be 3 but when you try to log `a` the variable `a` is undefined because variable declaration with `var` keyword has local scope and cannot access outside its scope.

So, this tells you:

```
var a = b = 3;
//b = 3; //global scope //first it assigns b = 3.
//var a = 3;//local scope //then assigns a = 3.
```

Answer (score 4):

```
(function() {
    var a = b = 3;
})();

console.log(a, b);
```

When a IIFE is created , a function is created and is called.Here a is the local variable and variables have local scope so you cant access it outside

You havent used var in front of b so it becomes the global variable and hence is reflected outside the function scope too

Answer (score 1):

Because in first function you declare local variable `var a` and print outside of function which not access local variable so it's undefined.

and 2nd function you print inside the function which access local variable so works well

Answer (score 1):

All the answers given are correct. I'm just trying to show what's happening using your own code, and to make everything involved super clear for others that come across this question. And I'm pretty much doing this for fun ;D

There are three things happening here:

1. *Associativity:* When assignments are made like the code given, everything flows from *right to left*, not left to right. so the expressions are effectively reordered.
2. *Scoping variables:* If you don't use var for each variable a given variable will be considered global, leaking outside of the local function scope. Multiple variables can be set up at the same time, using commas (`var a = 1, b = 2;`). This effectively copies over the `var` to each new variable, making each one locally scoped (equivalent to: `var a = 1; var b = 2;`).
3. *Global vs Local scope:* Code within the same scope (local to the same function, in this case) can see variables within that scope. Code outside of that scope (outside of the function, in this case) will only be able to see global variables that aren't bound within that function.

Let's have a look at the original code, to clear things up:

```
(function() {
    // var a = b = 3;
    b = 3; // no var, gets outside of the function's scope (known as global scope)
    var a = b; // with var, stays inside the function's scope (known as local scope)
})();

// we're outside of the function now
// we can't see any of the variables local to the function's scope, but we *can* see variables in the global scope

console.log(a, b);
// there is no `a` variable set in the global scope, so that value is given as `undefined`
// there is a `b` variable set in the global scope, so its value (3) is given

(function() {
    // var x = y = 3;
    y = 3; // global
    var x = y; // local

    // we're still inside the function, so we can still see its scoped variables
    console.log(x, y);
    // `x` is local, so its value (3) is used
    // `y` is global, and global variables can be seen from anywhere. so its value (3) is also used
})();
```

You could make everything local by changing the code to something like this:

```
(function() {
    var a = b = 3; // local a, global b
    // the original code

    var b, a = b = 3; // local a, local b
    // because of the comma, the `var` applies to all variables; 
equivalent to:
    // var b; // local; further assignments to `b` will stay local
    // b = 3; // local
    // var a = b; // local

    var b = 3, a = b; // local a, local b; equivalent to:
    // var b = 3;
    // var a = b;

    var a, b; a = b = 3; // local a, local b; equivalent to:
    // var a; var b;
    // b = 3; // local
    // a = b; // local
})();
```

Or make it all global by just leaving off the `var` entirely, like this:

```
(function() {
    var a = b = 3; // local a, global b
    // the original code

    a = b = 3; // global a, global b; equivalent to:
    // b = 3; // global
    // a = b; // global
})();
```

As you can see, it's very easy to let variables leak outside of the function's scope. So when coding we need to be sure `var` is applied to all variables we create, except for the rare case when we actually *want* a variable to be set globally.

One thing to keep in mind when setting up a local `var` is, *that* variable will "shadow" any global variable with the same name. When code is run, any locally-scoped variables will be used *before* it looks for the same variable name higher up the chain (if the function is nested in another function, or eventually all the way up to the global scope).